# Counting Sort displays a weird behavior

Tags: c, sorting, counting-sort

I have implemented a *Counting Sort* in an assignment given to us by a teacher but sometimes it doesn't work for large arrays.

Here is the code:

```
void countingSort(int *t, int n) {
    int min = findMin(t, n);
    int max = findMax(t, n);
    int range = max - min + 1;
    int *count, *output;
    int i;
    count = (int *)malloc(range * sizeof(int));
    output = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < range; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count[t[i] - min]++;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < range; i++) {
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[count[t[i] - min] - 1] = t[i];
        count[t[i] - min]--;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        t[i] = output[i];
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work for small values of `range`, but might fail if `min` and `max` are too far apart, causing the computation of `range` to overflow the range of `int` and `malloc()` to fail.

You should check for overflow in `range` and check memory allocation success. Note too that `calloc()` is more appropriate than `malloc()` for the `count` array. Finally, you must free the allocated arrays.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int findMax(const int *t, int n) {
    int max = INT_MIN;
    while (n-- > 0) {
        if (max < *t) max = *t;
        t++;
    }
    return max;
}    

int findMin(const int *t, int n) {
    int min = INT_MAX;
    while (n-- > 0) {
        if (min > *t) min = *t;
        t++;
    }
    return min;
}    

int countingSort(int *t, int n) {
    int min, max, range, i;
    int *count, *output;

    if (n <= 0)
        return 0; 

    min = findMin(t, n);
    max = findMax(t, n);

    if (min < 0 && max >= 0 && (unsigned)max + (unsigned)(-min) >= INT_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "countingSort: value range too large: %d..%d\n", min, max);
        return -1;
    }
    range = max - min + 1;
    if ((count = (int *)calloc(range, sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "countingSort: cannot allocate %d element count array\n", range);
        return -1;
    }
    if ((output = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "countingSort: cannot allocate %d element output array\n", n);
        free(count);
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count[t[i] - min]++;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < range; i++) {
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }
    for (i = n; i-- > 0;) {
        output[count[t[i] - min] - 1] = t[i];
        count[t[i] - min]--;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        t[i] = output[i];
    }
    free(count);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

You can avoid the cumbersome and potentially inefficient downward loop by replacing the second and third `for` loops with this:

```
    /* compute the first index for each value */
    int index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < range; i++) {
        incr = count[i];
        count[i] = index;
        index += incr;
    }
    /* copy each value at the corresponding index and update it */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        output[count[t[i] - min]++] = t[i];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. Also you are right `calloc` is much better than `malloc` in this case because it's thanks to it I can remove the for loop that initializes the count array with zeros.